# Which festivals trace their origin stories to Vedas

Tags: vedas, festivals

There are many hindu festivals. Most of them derive their origin in Itihaasa (Ramayana and Mahabharata) and Puranas.

So, are there any festivals that have their origin in Vedas ?

Comment: There is full moon sacrifice, new moon sacrifice, etc.

Comment: @Ikshvaku they are not festival. They are rituals

Comment: What do you mean by "festival" then?

Comment: @Ikshvaku by festival I mean holi, Diwali and Navratri. You can say that they have rituals but most of part of these festivals are celebrating and enjoying. Any way can you answer it. Not just that any festival that is celebrated in a grand way. Like diwali.